# How to remove PDF/A markers without using Adobe Acrobat in GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, pdfa

I am trying to remove the PDF/A markers in a file — I have no access to Adobe Acrobat — as some tools balk at PDF/As.  Is there a way to revert a PDF/A to a normal PDF with free software tools?  I am running Debian testing.

Comment: Every pdf/a is a pdf.

Comment: How would you like me to phrase it then?  The fact is that sometimes one needs a PDF not to be a PDF/A.

Comment: You want to stop a pdf/a to advertise itself as a pdf/a. Ryan's answer shows where it does so.

Answer (score 1):

The indicators for PDF/A are in the Metadata entry, but you do not want to erase that entire entry. Instead you would want to modify it.

To modify, you can extract the XML string, modify using whatever XML tool is handy for you, and then "update".

These three entries are the ones you want to erase.

```
pdfaid:part
pdfaid:amd
pdfaid:conformance
```

Of course this still leaves you with the following tasks, with 1 and 3 normally done using a PDF SDK library.

1. Find and extract the Metadata entry (it could be compressed in the PDF)
2. Reading and editing the XML (should be trivial)
3. Updating the Metadata entry with your modified XML

Since you gave no indications of platform+OS I can't advise any further.

Comment: In my case, metadata was not compressed, I managed to just erase pdfaid:part & pdfaid:conformance lines and it worked.  pdfaid:amd was not present, at least not in uncompressed form.  Anyway it worked: Adobe document cloud refused to share the file and now allows it, even when I re-uploaded it with a PDFA suffix.

Comment: OK, now I found a PDF/A with compressed metadata.  How to extract and update it in Debian GNU/Linux?

Comment: As I noted in my answer, for steps 1 and 3 you should be using a PDF library, and I specifically mentioned compression as a likely issue. If you are looking for a PDF library recommendation then StackOverflow is the wrong place. You would ask instead here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/